# GTK TextBuffer , finding whole words

Tags: c, gtk3, gtk-textbuffer

I am trying to compare words isolated in GTK textview against a list of keywords and cant seem to figure out how to do that. I am working(learning) in C.

```
gchar word[][10] = {"auto", "continue", "enum".....
```

I am moving iters word by word through the text buffer, then trying

```
gtk_text_iter_get_text(&start,&end);
```

so can end up with word[1] as "auto" and the iters finding the word "auto" in the textview. but cant find a way to compare them to confirm a match. attempts to use gtk_text_iter_forward_search() results in things like highlighting the "auto" in **auto**mobile.

I have tried 'strcmp()' but that always returns true no matter what is in the text view.

I am working on syntax highlighting kind of thing and have comments , single/double quotes, escape sequence/format specifiers and numbers all able to highlight but am stuck on getting highlighting on words, any nudge in the right direction is appreciated.

Comment: `strcmp()` does not return a boolean. I suggest to read the manual.

Comment: thank you , I was probably looking at strcmp() the wrong way , it returns a 0 for a match or greater than / less than 0 otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to this by checking if the textiters where at the start and end of a word.

```
  while (1){
     
     if(gtk_text_iter_forward_search(&end, word[loop], GTK_TEXT_SEARCH_TEXT_ONLY,
                                                            &start, &end, &stop)){
        if (gtk_text_iter_starts_word(&start) && gtk_text_iter_ends_word(&end)){
           gtk_text_buffer_apply_tag(buffer, word_tag, &start, &end);
        }
        else{
           gtk_text_iter_forward_word_end(&end);
           gtk_text_buffer_remove_tag(buffer, word_tag, &start, &end);
        }
     }
     else
        break;
  }
```

inside a for loop that iterates the array of C keywords, so now if I type 'auto' it will highlight , but if I carry on to 'automobile', the text tag is removed. the while loop scans the line the cursor is in and the line above word by word. I am only a month into learning C and GTK so not very advanced but maybe posting the solution I found will help some one else that is just learning too.

Comment: Set your `gtk_text_buffer_get_start_iter (buffer, &start);`  Now loop until you find a word start iterator with, e.g. `while (!gtk_text_iter_starts_word (&start)) { gtk_text_iter_forward_char (&start); }`. Set `end = start;`. Your search will look like `while (gtk_text_iter_forward_word_end (&end)) { const gchar *word = gtk_text_buffer_get_text (buffer, &start, &end, FALSE); /* handle word */ start = end; /* set up for next word find */ for (;;) { if (!gtk_text_iter_forward_char (&start)) goto done; if (gtk_text_iter_starts_word (&start)) break;` repeat total loop to find all words.

Comment: A full example of one [function to find each work in text-buffer](https://github.com/drankinatty/gtkwrite/blob/6b2c8c852a4df8c64935ced594de8f87fb60ccfb/gtk_filebuf.c#L492) That should get you going.

Comment: thank you , I think I came across that example before. I book marked that to look over. I think I will stick to gtk_text_iter_forward_search for now because I think either way I end up at the same place and have to scan closer at the words anyways because word end and word start ignore an underscore and _int should not highlight.